# I just started learning html. What does the term 'predefined tag' mean?

Tags: html

There are many predefined tags like 'dfn', 'code', 'em', etc.
What is the purpose of these tags?

Comment: Have you attempted to read any tutorials/search?

Answer (score 3):

"Predefined", in this context, means that it's a standard HTML tag that you can reasonably expect to be honored by any sensible browsed. The tags you listed are all tags for text formatting:

- `dfn` stands for "definition", and is often displayed as *italic* text
- `code` stands for, well, code, and is often styled with a `monospaced font`.
- `em` stands for "emphasized", and is often displayed as *italic* text too.

Comment: @ankhzet yup, that's correct. Edited and fixed. Thanks for noticing!